# How to compare order of magnitude?

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

In Fan and Li's paper "[Variable Selection via Nonconcave Penalized Likelihood and its Oracle Properties](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~jqfan/papers/01/penlike.pdf)", they provided a proof to Theorem 1. The very last part of the proof is as follows.

[image]

Some notations: $L(\boldsymbol \beta_0)$ is log-likelihood function, $\mathbf{u}$ is a constant vector, $I(\boldsymbol \beta_0)$ is Expected Fisher information, $p'_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{j0}|)$ is a penalty function; $\alpha_n = n^{-1/2} + a_n$, and $a_n = \text{max} \{p'_{\lambda_n}(|\beta_{j0}|): \beta_{j0} \neq 0 \}$

Given that you already know $n^{-1/2} L'(\boldsymbol \beta_0) = O_p(1)$, and that the third term in (A.2) is bounded by the term stated (I figured out these two claims), my questions are:

1. Why is "$O_p(n^{1/2} \alpha_n) = O_p(n\alpha_n^2)$"? I am confused with this claim since it's really counter-intuitive. Should it be "$O_p(n^{1/2} \alpha_n) < O_p(n\alpha_n^2)$"?
2. Why does the second term dominate the first and the third term?

Any insights are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What does $O_p$ stand for? Is it [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)?

Comment: It's big-O notation in probability. It means "bounded in probability", or stochastic boundness. See wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation